# Bash basename syntax

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a script that takes the basename of an argument, then checks if there is an extension in that argument. If there is, it prints the extension.

Here is my code:

```
file=basename $1
ext=${file%*}
echo ${file#"$stub"}
echo $basename $1
```

I'm echoing the final $basename $1 to check what the output of basename is.

Some tests reveal:

```
testfile.sh one.two
./testfile: line 2: one.two: command not found
one.two

testfile.sh ../tester
./testfile: line 2: ../tester: No such file or directory
../tester
```

So neither $basename $1 are working. I know it's a syntax error so could someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

I've solved my problem now with:

```
file=$(basename "$1" )
stub=${file%.*}
echo ${file#"$stub"}
```

Which reduces my argument to a basename, thank you all.

Comment: The correct syntax is file=$(basename $1). I would recommend you to use file=${1##*/}, which will remove every '*/' sequence. It is actually much faster than the basename command, especially when processing files in a loop.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, your syntax is wrong:

```
file=$( basename "$1" )
```

Second, this is the correct expression to get the file name's (last) extension:

```
ext=${file##*.}
```

Comment: Thanks for the first part,I realize that now the file is equal to the output of basename, so that helps. Now my program isn't working as intended, meaning it's ouputting tester.two instead of .two if my initial argument is tester.two. Before I added basename, my script was ouputting as intended aside from when I tested ../tester, which should output nothing.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to assign to a variable the output of a command, you must execute it, either with back quotes or using a special parenthesis quoting:

```
file=`basename "$1"`
file=$(basename "$1")
```

To remove a filename's extension you should do

```
ext=${file#*.}
```

this will get the value of `$file`, then remove everything up to the period (that's why it is necessary). If your filename contains periods, then you should use `ext=${file##*.}`, where the `##` tells bash to delete the longest string that matches instead of the shortest, so it will delete up to the last period, instead of the first one.

Your `echo $basename $1` is wierd. It is telling bash to print the value of a variable called `$basename` and the value of the variable `$1`, which is the first argument to the script (or function).

If you want to print the command you're trying to execute, do this:

```
echo basename $1
```

If you're trying to print the output of the command, you can do one of:

```
echo $(basename "$1")
echo "$file"
basename "$1"
```

Hope this helps =)